# Convert datetime based on timezone in other column in R

Tags: r, timezone, tidyverse, lubridate

Below timezone tibble that match country with selected timezone correct with OlsonNames(), and sample data with dates with timezone UTC0

```
Timezone <- tibble(
  Country = c("Germany", "Poland", "Austria", "Hungary", "Czech Republic", "Ireland", "Cyprus", "Egypt",
              "Spain", "France", "Greece", "Croatia", "Italy", "Morocco", "Portugal", "Bulgaria", "Romania",
              "Switzerland", "Denmark", "Estonia", "Iceland", "Lithuania", "Latvia", "Montenegro", "Malta",
              "Netherlands", "Norway", "Slovenia", "Slovakia", "United Kingdom", "Sweden", "Ukraine"),
  tz_new = c("Europe/Berlin", "Europe/Warsaw", "Europe/Vienna", "Europe/Budapest", "Europe/Prague",
               "Europe/Dublin", "Asia/Nicosia", "Africa/Cairo", "Europe/Madrid", "Europe/Paris", "Europe/Athens",
               "Europe/Zagreb", "Europe/Rome", "Africa/Casablanca", "Europe/Lisbon", "Europe/Sofia", "Europe/Bucharest",
               "Europe/Zurich", "Europe/Copenhagen", "Europe/Tallinn", "Atlantic/Reykjavik", "Europe/Vilnius", "Europe/Riga",
               "Europe/Podgorica", "Europe/Malta", "Europe/Amsterdam", "Europe/Oslo", "Europe/Ljubljana", "Europe/Bratislava",
               "Europe/London", "Europe/Stockholm", "Europe/Kiev")
)

#sample df 
temp <- tibble(
  ID = 1:5,
  Value = c(10, 20, 15, 30, 25),
  Country = c("Morocco", "Iceland", "Ireland", "Germany", "Poland"),
  Date1 = as.POSIXct(c("2023-08-08 12:00:00", "2023-08-08 13:00:00", "2023-08-08 14:00:00", "2023-08-08 15:00:00", "2023-08-08 16:00:00"), tz = "UTC"),
  Date2 = as.POSIXct(c("2023-08-09 12:00:00", "2023-08-09 13:00:00", "2023-08-09 14:00:00", "2023-08-09 15:00:00", "2023-08-09 16:00:00"), tz = "UTC"),
  Date3 = as.POSIXct(c("2023-08-10 12:00:00", "2023-08-10 13:00:00", "2023-08-10 14:00:00", "2023-08-10 15:00:00", "2023-08-10 16:00:00"), tz = "UTC")
)
```

I created Timezone tibble and join it to my data. Tried to convert dates to timezone based on tz_new but without success. It convert by first matched timezone

```
df <-temp %>%
left_join(Timezone, by = "Country") %>%
group_by(tz_new) %>%
mutate(across(where(is.POSIXct), ~with_tz(.x, tz_new)
```

Comment: You can't have multiple timezones in a single datetime vector. Alternate solutions may include working with UTC until you need to convert to timezone at the end of the analysis, converting the date vectors to lists which can then have their own unique timezone, splitting the data so you have 1 dataframe per country.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks NicChr comment i changed code and test it

```
data <- temp%>%
  left_join(Timezone, by = "Country") %>%
  group_nest(Country) %>%
  mutate(data = map(data, ~ mutate(.x, across(where(is.POSIXct), ~ with_tz(.x, tzone = tz_new)))))
```

Above code convert well different timezone, but when i unnest(data) then it allow only one timezone